# Docker bash'ing with find

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am having a hell of a time attempting to get a bash script to work as expected (as it does in a normal bash session) on a Docker run.

The goal is to replace all of the symlinked files within the official java container with their actual file within the JAVA_HOME directory, so everything is contained within the java directory and not outside of it, 
e.g.

`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy` <--- is symlinked to ---> `/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.policy`

The end result should be the file located at: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy`

The setup:

`docker run java:7u91 /bin/bash -cxe "find /usr/lib/jvm/**/jre -type l | while read f; do echo $f; cp --remove-destination $(readlink $f) $f; done;"`

I had attempted several different methods of effectively this, with xargs and exec all to no avail.

Any suggestions at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: If you SSH in (`docker exec -it java:7u91 bash`), and run the command `find /usr/lib/jvm/**/jre -type l | while read f; do echo $f; cp --remove-destination $(readlink $f) $f; done;`, what output/feedback do you get?  It's going to be a lot easier to debug inside of the machine rather than trying to look in from the outside.

Comment: On a number of the files I am getting:
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/tz.properties’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/calendars.properties’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.

However if I ls -l the file it is not a symlink and it a file...?

Comment: It looks like this is what is happening: `$(readlink $f)` is not returning anything on the files that are not symbolic links (only works on symbolic links).  Therefore, that expression is essentially nothing/empty.  

So, only the `$f` is returning a value.  Therefore, if the expression was evaluated, it would print `cp --remove-destination VALUE_OF_$F;`, and the `$f` would look like it was the first parameter of the `cp` command, with no second parameter present.  That is why the 'destination' is missing.

Comment: It looks like you have the find statement correctly set up, with the `-type l` only returning symbolic links.  I am not sure why you are getting some empty values then..

Comment: using sed -i seems to fix the issue from inside the container:
`find /usr/lib/jvm/**/jre -type l | while read f; do sed -i '' $f; done;` 
however from the outside still getting an error:
`sed: no input files
+ read f
+ sed -i ''`

Comment: Try putting everything in single quotes, rather than double quotes.  There is a chance that your variables are being parsed on your host rather than inside of the docker container.  Single quotes may do the trick you are looking for.  If that doesn't work, you may consider putting the commands in a bash file and running the bash file in the docker container.

Comment: And that was exactly right.  That was a silly issue.  If you answer the question ill accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what is happening: `$(readlink $f)` is not returning anything on the files that are not symbolic links (only works on symbolic links).  Therefore, that expression is essentially nothing/empty.

So, only the `$f` is returning a value.  Therefore, if the expression was evaluated, it would print `cp --remove-destination VALUE_OF_$F;`, and the `$f` would look like it was the first parameter of the `cp` command, with no second parameter present.  That is why the 'destination' is missing.

Also, you need to consider the fact that putting your command inside of double quotes like that is presenting a problem.  The variables will be parsed on the host rather than in the docker container.  Replace the double quotes with single quotes to prevent that from happening.